# Does this Patent mean that no one else can produce or sell E-Cigs with vitamin in them?

Tags: application, us20100200008

Does this US Patent Application mean that no one else can manufacture or sell electronic cigarettes with vitamins in them?

I was thinking vitamins combined with e-cigarettes would be a great idea for a great start up company and I couldn't really find any out there.  Is it because of this patent application?

Patent: [**US20100200008**](http://www.google.com/patents/us20100200008)

Title:  **E-Cigarette With Vitamin Infusion**

First claim:

> 1. An electronic cigarette comprising:
>
>    - a main elongated cylindrical body for enclosing said electronic cigarette, said body having an anterior and distal end;
>    - a cartridge, having atomization means, and a liquid supplying bottle wherein liquid in said liquid supplying bottle is in contact with said atomization means;
>    - a power source having a smart chip, control panel and a lithium ion rechargeable battery for transferring heat to said liquid in said liquid supplying bottle;
>    - an IC switch for releasing a signal to activate and deactivate said power source; and
>    - an LED indicator light positioned at said distal end for simulating the tip of a traditionally lit cigarette when said power source is activated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a patent *application*, as the questioner says. Patent applications provide no enforceable rights, only a granted and issued patent give its owner any rights to try to stop someone from doing something. I looked this application up in the [USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database and see that it has gone abandoned for lack of a response to an Office Action from the USPTO. The primary rejection was:

> Claims 1-8 are rejected under 35 U.S.C. 103(a) as being unpatentable over Hon (US 2007/026731